# Run "python manage.py runserver" from a bash script

Tags: python, django, bash, selenium, hudson

I want to run  "python manage.py runserver" from a bash script

First if I wanted to run from a terminal "python manage.py runserver &" but it doesn't work. I found the fix for this in (https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16327). Manually in a terminal running "python manage.py runserver &" works fine. 
I've added in a bash script "python manage.py runserver &" but it doesn't start the server.

```
Error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 137, in main
    reloader(main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 110, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 89, in reloader_thread
    ensure_echo_on()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in ensure_echo_on
    attr_list = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Comment: Why oh why oh why not just use a normal deployment mechanism...

Comment: I want to run this command from a job in Hudson (Add Build Step -> Execute shell). After the server is started run nosetests

Comment: That is the wrong way to do it. Unit tests - including nose - should use the built-in test server and client from the code, not access the actual development server.

Comment: @Daniel My goal is to have a Hudson job that is doing the following: update sources from SVN, start selenium server jar, run server "python manage.py runserver" (This is my problem) , run Selenium automated tests using command nosetests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably that hudson is not running as your user... you could run

```
source /home/your_user/.bashrc && django_serve
```

to make it run that alias, but I think you'll probably need to switch users

-- or --

have hudson run the dev server from it's own checkout of the source

**Edit**: Looking at your erro though, I think this may solve your problem:

instead of

```
python manage.py runserver
```

try adding the `--noreload` flag to disable the auto reloader

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: I've done the following: 1. add in .bash_aliases `alias django_server='python manage.py runserver --noreload &'` (Without the `--noreload` option I get the initial error described above) 2. copy ~/.bash_aliases /var/lib/hudson. 3. In the Hudson job (Add Build Step -> Execute shell) add `. /var/lib/hudson/.bash_aliases` and `django_server`. Server is running in background and Selenium tests are running using nosetests. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use alias to start django server. May be can help)

Just add `alias django_serve="python manage.py runserver &"` at the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Also you create `.bash_aliases` and place your aliases into this file and execute it before you make any actions like

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: I've added `alias django_server="python manage.py runserver &"` in `~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc`. I run command `django_server` from terminal and works fine. Then I've done a bash script that contains `django_server` but it tell me `command not found`.